# web browser print preview xml with xls don't break the td correct

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

When I show my XML file in IE11 and select show print preview it looks fine, but is I load the XML into the webbrowser object via C# and use the webbrowser.showprintpreview the page breaks are not working correctly.

my XLS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <title>Report printed by DFrk(Danny Frank)</title>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table { page-break-after: auto }                        
            tr    { page-break-inside: avoid !important;}  
            td    {  
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-family: Arial; 
                font-size: 10pt;
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: left;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;              
                }
            div { page-break-inside: avoid !important;  }
            th    { page-break-inside: avoid; 
                font-family: Arial; 
                font-size: 10pt;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: left;
                border-bottom: 1px solid Gainsboro;
                background-color: SteelBlue;
                color: white; }
        @media print {
            thead {display: table-header-group }
            tfoot {display: table-footer-group }
            .noPrint {display: none }
            .noScreen{display: none}
        }
        @media screen {
            .noPrint{}
            .noScreen{display: none }
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="ex1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>

                <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><img src="..\..\Img\ANLogo vandret.jpg" height="100" width="150"><h2>Connfigurated tags</h2></img></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <div>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </div>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="configuration/tags/tag">
                <tr>
                    <div>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="@description"/></td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
       </table>
   </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

And my XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Konfiguration_style.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <template>
    <name>Tags</name>
    <version>001</version>
    <description>Configuration of tags for OPC</description>
    <changelog version="001" auther="DFrk">First version</changelog>
  </template>
  <tags id="parameterfilelist" description="List of tags" allowmulti="false">
    <tag id="Tag1" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.Prod.TankPresAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag2" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.Prod.KrystTidAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag3" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.TjekpH.MinpH"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag4" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.TjekpH.MaxpH"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag5" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.pHJust.MinStartpH"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag6" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.pHJust.CF_Limit"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag7" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.pHJust.pHSetPunktLowAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag8" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.pHJust.pHSetPunktHighAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag9" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.pHJust.GrovDoseringsTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag10" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.pHJust.GrovPauseTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag11" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.pHJust.FinDoseringsTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag12" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.pHJust.FinPauseTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag13" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.pHJust.MaxpHJusteringsTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag14" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.Transfere.GramAktivStof"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag15" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.Transfere.RestMængde"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag16" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.Transfere.TankNiveauForLSL"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag17" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.Kryst.KrystalMaxDeltaVægt"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag18" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.Kryst.HighTempAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag19" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.Kryst.LowTempAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag20" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD131.Dv.E.InsulinOpl.OmrørTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag21" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.Prod.TankPresAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag22" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.Prod.KrystTidAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag23" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.TjekpH.MinpH"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag24" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.TjekpH.MaxpH"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag25" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.pHJust.MinStartpH"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag26" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.pHJust.CF_Limit"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag27" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.pHJust.pHSetPunktLowAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag28" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.pHJust.pHSetPunktHighAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag29" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.pHJust.GrovDoseringsTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag30" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.pHJust.GrovPauseTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag31" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.pHJust.FinDoseringsTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag32" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.pHJust.FinPauseTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag33" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.pHJust.MaxpHJusteringsTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag34" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.Transfere.GramAktivStof"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag35" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.Transfere.RestMængde"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag36" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.Transfere.TankNiveauForLSL"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag37" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.Kryst.KrystalMaxDeltaVægt"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag38" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.Kryst.HighTempAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag39" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.Kryst.LowTempAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag40" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD132.Dv.E.InsulinOpl.OmrørTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag41" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.Prod.TankPresAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag42" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.Prod.KrystTidAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag43" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.TjekpH.MinpH"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag44" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.TjekpH.MaxpH"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag45" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.pHJust.MinStartpH"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag46" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.pHJust.CF_Limit"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag47" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.pHJust.pHSetPunktLowAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag48" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.pHJust.pHSetPunktHighAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag49" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.pHJust.GrovDoseringsTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag50" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.pHJust.GrovPauseTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag51" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.pHJust.FinDoseringsTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag52" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.pHJust.FinPauseTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag53" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.pHJust.MaxpHJusteringsTid"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag54" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.Transfere.GramAktivStof"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag55" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.Transfere.RestMængde"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag56" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.Transfere.TankNiveauForLSL"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag57" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.Kryst.KrystalMaxDeltaVægt"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag58" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.Kryst.HighTempAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag59" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.Kryst.LowTempAdv"></tag>
    <tag id="Tag60" type="text" description="Q::KaDDK8Kryst:StartMaster.KaDD133.Dv.E.InsulinOpl.OmrørTid"></tag>
  </tags>
</configuration>
```

And the code use including the transform:

```
    private void DisplayXml()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        // Load the xslt used by IE to render the xml
        XslCompiledTransform xTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xTrans.Load("Konfiguration_style.xsl");

        doc.Load("TagsKaDDK8Kryst.xml");

        // Transform the XML data
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        xTrans.Transform(doc, null, ms);

        ms.Position = 0;

        Program.opcTool.setErrorTextInStatusBar(webBrowser1.Version.ToString());

        // Set to the document stream
        webBrowser1.DocumentStream = ms;
        this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
    }
```

[Page two where id is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP8Tr.jpg)

[page one where the id that should be in page two is showing in the buttom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgxIN.jpg)

The id column doesn't get the right page-break-inside Avoid for some reason that I can't find when using the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>` in the XSLT. And move `<title>Report printed by DFrk(Danny Frank)</title>` inside of the `head` element.

Comment: Didn't help. :(